# Unable to add browser platform or any platform in Cordova Cli 7.0.1

Tags: cordova, browser, platform, cordova-cli

installed 
node.js 7.7.1
cordova cli 7.0.1

this error appeared in CLI

> cordova platform add browser
>
> Error: Failed to fetch platform cordova-browser@~4.1.0Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect
>   Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
>   Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT

Comment: i had to use visual studio 2017 to create a cordova project which had the platforms installed automatically. and run on browser or device .